# Rails 4: deauthorize all users in facebook app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4, koala

I just committed a mistake when developing and now I do not know how to fix it...

Im using Koala for integrate my facebook app with my rails app, I have a staging and a production environment, my mistake is that my staging app was using the same facebook app that was using my production env, so the users do not match, so now in my production env Im getting 'undefined method for nil:nilclass bla blab bla

How can I just deauthorize all users in my facebook app? so I force users to authorize the app again, that way I could fix the problem but I do not know how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found de-authorize just one user is manually with curl:

```
curl -X DELETE "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=#{token}"
```

So I think you need valid access token for every user.